# How can I can the value of soup.html.text or soup.html.string in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So, `soup.html.text` gives me all the text inside all of the tags. But how can I change it to something different like

```py
soup.html.text = 'some text'
```

The above gives me an `AttributeError`.
Or simply saying I can't do this

```py
soup.html.text = soup.html.text
```

Is there a way to do it or I'm just doing something `BeautifulSoup` is not capable of?

Comment: You assign to `.string` to change the contents of an element, not `.text`.

Comment: `.text` is obsolete, it has been replaced with the `.get_text()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> You can’t edit a string in place, but you can replace one string with another, using [`replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with)

```
tag.string.replace_with('new text')
```